# bit store order in memory

Tags: c, memory, bit

X86 machine, OS: Linux 2.6 RH.
Here are my codes:

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    typedef struct ch_t
    {
        int c0:1;
        int c1:1;
        int c2:1;
        int c3:1;
        int c4:1;
        int c5:1;
        int c6:1;
        int c7:1;
    } ch;

    typedef union chh_u
    {
        char a;
        ch chat;
    } chh;
    int main(void)
    {
        chh uu;
        uu.a = 6;
        printf("\n%d", uu.chat.c0);
        printf("\n%d", uu.chat.c1);
        printf("\n%d", uu.chat.c2);
        printf("\n%d", uu.chat.c3);
        printf("\n%d", uu.chat.c4);
        printf("\n%d", uu.chat.c5);
        printf("\n%d", uu.chat.c6);
        printf("\n%d", uu.chat.c7);
        printf("\n%d\n", uu.a);
        return 0;
    }
```

As I expected, the output should be:

> 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 6

But the actual output was:

> 0
>   -1
>   -1 0 0 0 0 0 6

I can't understand why output above.
I think 6 bit order is 0000 0110, and in memory, in my option, the bit order also is 0000 0110. But the output shows difference.

Can some one explain this?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Why not?

Comment: Please do not call your own types `something_t`. Types whose name ends in `_t` are reserved for the operating system and its headers.

Comment: @FUZxxl IMO, usually, using `%d` you can run into situation like above. in case of 1 bit, it will consider `signed` value. It's always better to use `unsigned` type for bitfield variables.

Comment: @SouravGhosh If that's what you mean, your comment is wrong. `%d` is the correct format specifier for a `signed int`. You might want to rewrite your comment.

Comment: @FUZxxl ok, now I see the point. Will delete the first comment to avoid confusion. thanks, BTW.

Comment: using 'int' in a bit definition is not correct,  as a single bit cannot be signed.  so use: 'unsigned int

Answer (score 4):

The relevant parts of the standard are 6.7.2 (5).

> Each of the comma-separated sets designates the same type, **except that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.**

...this explains why you (can) get -1 instead of 1 for the set bits. The other is 6.7.2.1 (10):

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next bits or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. **The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.** The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

So that, too, could go either way.

Addendum: Since there appears to be some confusion about this: Calling a function with a variable argument list with bit-fields are fine if the function expects an `int` inside, for the same reasons that it is fine to say

```
char c = '\xff';
printf("%d\n", c); // will usually print 255 or -1
```

and it can give different results for precisely the same reasons, because just like the bit-field, a `char` can be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation. I'll quote the relevant bits with irrelevant parts cut out this time because these rules are buried in somewhat tediously legalese parts of the C99 standard. They are found in 6.5.2.2 (6):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, **the integer promotions are performed on each argument**, and arguments that have type `float` are converted to `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*. (...)

and 6.5.2.2 (7):

> (...) The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. **The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments**.

The integer promotions are defined in 6.3.1.1; the relevant bit is in paragraphs 2 and 3:

> 2 The following may be used whereever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - (...)
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int` or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. (...)
>
> 3 The integer promotions preserve value including sign. (...)

So, this happens:

1. Your compiler treats `int` bit-fields as signed
2. This means that a bit-field of width 1 with its bit set has value -1; it is, in a manner of speaking, only the sign, and it is set.
3. In passing to `printf` it is converted, preserving this value, to `int`
4. This int is printed by `printf` according to the `%d` format string and gives you "-1".
5. Profit?

Answer (score 1):

Try making the values in your bitfield `unsigned`. This avoids the unexpected behaviour you experience.

```
typedef struct ch_t {
    unsigned int c0:1;
    unsigned int c1:1;
    unsigned int c2:1;
    unsigned int c3:1;
    unsigned int c4:1;
    unsigned int c5:1;
    unsigned int c6:1;
    unsigned int c7:1;
} ch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you're creating a `signed int` [usually, `int` defaults to `signed int`] type `bitfield` variable and trying to print the value using `%d` format specifier. Sadly, this will not give you proper value for single-bit bitfields.

As clarified by @wintermute in his comment, while using the bitfielded variables directly in `printf()`, they're considered as `signed integer`. OTOH, as per the rule, a single bit `signed integer` can have the value of either `0` or `-1` and therefore, in this case the representation will be `-1`.

Also, *in your case*, I assume you understand `c0` is the `LSB` and `c7` will be `MSB`, right?

You need to take out the required bit before printing. Try something like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct ch_t
{
        int c0:1;
        int c1:1;
        int c2:1;
        int c3:1;
        int c4:1;
        int c5:1;
        int c6:1;
        int c7:1;
} ch;

typedef union chh_u
{
        char a;
        ch chat;
} chh;
int main(void)
{
        chh uu;
        uu.a = 6;
        printf("\n%d", (uu.chat.c0) && 0x01);
        printf("\n%d", (uu.chat.c1) && 0x01);
        printf("\n%d", (uu.chat.c2) && 0x01);
        printf("\n%d", (uu.chat.c3) && 0x01);
        printf("\n%d", (uu.chat.c4) && 0x01);
        printf("\n%d", (uu.chat.c5) && 0x01);
        printf("\n%d", (uu.chat.c6) && 0x01);
        printf("\n%d", (uu.chat.c7) && 0x01);
        printf("\n%d\n", uu.a);
        return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, use `unsigned int` datatype in your structure definition.

Comment: The bit-field is converted to int in the variadic parameter list. The values he gets are fine, they're just considered signed by his compiler and extended to an `int` with value -1.

Comment: @Wintermute Right you are. Will add this reference into my answer, with your permission. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In `struct ch_t`, the bitfields `c0`..`c7` occupy the lower 8 bits, with `c0` as the lowest (2^0) and `c7` as the highest (2^7).  Arranged from highest to lowest, like when writing a binary number, you have `c7 c6 c5 c4 c3 c2 c1 c0`.  The number 6, in 8 binary digits, is `00000110`, so that means `c2` and `c1` contain `1` bits, and the rest contain `0` bits.  This matches the result you got, where those fields showed `-1`.

The reason they display as `-1` instead of `1` is because you've used `int` instead of `unsigned int` for your bitfields.  This effectively gives you a signed integer type of 1 bit, which for 2's compliment can hold only 0 or -1.